# How can I compare two version numbers that are strings in the format x.y.z?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
var v2 = "1.0.3";
var v1 = "0.12.1";
```

Note there are always three numbers separated by a period and the numbers range from 0-99.

Any suggestions on how I could compare and find out if v2 is a newer version that v1 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8) class to do this:

```
var v2 = Version.Parse("1.0.3");
var v1 = Version.Parse("0.12.1");
if (v2 > v1)
    Console.WriteLine("v2 is newer");
```